# How to create an "Exit program" command

Tags: c

How could I make a line of code that would exit out of my program after input is given by the user for a specific word?

the psuedo-code of what I have is as follows:

take input;

compare (input) to exit word;

if input is same as exit word

exit the program <------- help here;

else

rest of program;

Comment: Input: scanf (or a safer equivalent). Compare: str(i)cmp. Exit: break/return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the code is inside main, you can simply use `return` if somewhere else use `exit`

Comment: exit(); is a function in stdlib.h.You should pass "1" to if the exit is because of undefined behavior else pass "0".

Answer (score 0):

Use the `exit()` function.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of sounding too terse, `exit();`